# MikTex CJK Windows font issue

Tags: fonts, xetex, miktex, cjk

I usually use the MS Mincho font for doing Japanese stuff. However, with XeLatex the following  creates gobbledegook:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
% Font should be available on windows
\setCJKmainfont{MS Mincho}

\begin{document}
見た
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I change out the "MS Mincho" for "SimSun" it renders perfectly fine. I have MS Mincho installed on my computer, so why can't I use it?

Comment: What version of XeLateX will be started? Look in the beginning of the log file, with your MWE on a recently updated MiKTeX I’ve got “XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9)”. Your MWE worked fine here, but I have only “msmincho.ttc” installed, cf. Michael Madsen’s answer.

Comment: For comparison: I’ve just updated my TeX Live portable and compiled the MWE. The log file tells me “XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX)”. So, the version numbers are the same.

Comment: Mine ends in "99975". Michael Madsen's answer solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This mailing list message](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-October/018702.html) seems to deal with the same issue, and it is apparently caused by the [presence of multiple versions](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-October/018703.html) of the MS Mincho font (both .ttc and .ttf files). You should be able to see the files if you open a command prompt in C:\Windows\Fonts and write `dir msmincho*`. It *should* be safe to delete the .ttf version, and that should fix your problem.

This bug may be MikTeX-specific; I have both of those files, but I use [TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/), and your example compiles as expected for me. (In fairness, however, I just updated everything a few hours ago, so you should probably try that first.)

Comment: It is not a really a bug but a side-effect: xetex consists of two parts (the real xetex engine and the driver xdvipdfmx) and if two font versions exists one part *can* find a different version than the other. Miktex and TeXLive differ in the fontconfig configuration: E.g. if a font is installed in a texmf tree it can be that only miktex actually sees it. So TeXSystem can be affected differently when two versions of a font exist in a system.